# Generics and class conversion

Tags: java, generics, wrapper, primitive, unchecked

I'm trying to generify old code, and there is some code where, given something like `Integer.class`, it returns `Integer.TYPE` (and vice-versa), and so on for the rest of the wrappers (if the input is not a wrapper, it returns the input class).  This seems like a candidate for conversion (if it doesn't already exist somewhere).  So, I have something like this:

```
public static <T> Class<T> convert(Class<T> type) {
    if (type == Integer.class) return Integer.TYPE;
    // and so on
    return type;
}
```

The problem with this code is that the compiler does not, by itself, know that in the if block we have ascertained that `T == Integer`, and thus does not know that returning `Integer.TYPE` is OK, thus barfing.  Of course, we can always explicitly cast to `Class<T>`.  The question is, is this cast safe, and thus I can be comfortable in adding the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` should be fine here: we know each wrapper class `W` declares its `TYPE` field as a `Class<W>`, - probably just add a comment to explain that rational.

Note that [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) already has [`Primitives.unwrap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29) to handle this for you, in case you're using it.

Comment: As stated in the question, I return the input if `type` does not represent a primitive type or its wrapper.  Still safe, right?

Comment: Yes - sorry, didn't read carefully enough. Actually the linked Guava method seems to have that same behavior.